# Return in Recursive Function

Tags: python, recursion, return

I have just started learning python (v3.2.3) and have encountered an odd problem about the `return` in this function:

```
def test(x):
    if x > 9 :
        test(x - 10)
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x

x = int(input())
y = test(x)
print('this should be real value',y)
```

When I run it, I get:

```
45
real value 5
this should be real value None
```

But I expected:

```
45
real value 5
this should be real value 5
```

I tried adding `return x` outside of `if` and I got the default input value.  Can anyone please explain how `return` works?

Comment: It is exactly the same as with a non-recursive call: if you want to propagate the return value from the function you called, you have to do that yourself, with the `return` keyword. Calling a function produces its return value, but it's up to you to do something with that return value, whether the called function is recursive or not.

Answer (score 98):

You invoke `test(45)`. This tests whether `45 > 9`, which is true, so it invokes `test(35)` (45 - 10), without returning its result. The same thing happens with `test(25)` and `test(15)`, until finally `test(5)` is invoked.

This prints 'real value 5', and then returns 5. But returning a result from a function **always** returns it to the direct caller of this function. It doesn't jump immediately out through several calls; after all, the caller might want to do something with the returned result before returning something to *it's* caller. In this case though, only `test(5)` returns anything at all; all the others call `test(x - 10)`, wait for that to return, ignore whatever it does return, and then (implicitly) return `None`. Since the outermost invocation `test(45)` is one of these cases, what you get is `None`.

Here's an attempt at a visualisation of what happens:

```
test(45):
| test(35):
| | test(25):
| | | test(15):
| | | | test(5):
| | | | | print('real value',5)
| | | | | return 5 to test(15)
| | | | return None to test(25)
| | | return None to test(35)
| | return None to test(45)
| return None
```

You didn't call `test(5)` in the interpreter, `test(5)` was called from inside another function call. So the return from `test(5)` goes to *that function call*. The fact that this is a function calling itself is *completely irrelevant*. You'd get exactly the same results if your code looked like this:

```
def test45(x):
    if x > 9 :
        test35(x - 10)
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x

def test35(x):
    if x > 9 :
        test25(x - 10)
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x

def test25(x):
    if x > 9 :
        test15(x - 10)
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x

def test15(x):
    if x > 9 :
        test5(x - 10)
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x

def test5(x):
    if x > 9 :
        print 'No more tests :('
    else:
        print('real value',x)
        return x
```

The test(x) function you call with 'x=45' is same as calling `test45(45)`. I hope you can see why it's obvious that `None` should be returned when recursion *isn't* involved. Well, when recursion is involved, nothing changes. The `return` statement neither knows nor cares whether it's returning from a recursively invoked function, it behaves exactly the same way in either case.

In fact, recursion isn't anything "special" at all; it behaves exactly the same way as ordinary function calls. You receive information from the thing that called you via arguments, and you return information to the thing that called you by returning. If you don't return something (perhaps only in one arm of an `if`), then `None` will be returned to your caller, regardless of whether you call any other function in that branch, regardless of what that function might return if you do call something, and regardless of whether the function you call happens to be the same function you're inside.

Answer (score 31):

The return is indented so it only executes in the else branch. If the first branch is taken, the function implicitly returns None.

You need to change this to

```
return test(x-10)
```

Comment: so does this mean that i need to have return even on the false unexecuted if condition ?

Comment: @AlexKey: Yes. Since `y` is assigned the value from the first function call only. This is not something that is unique to Python. The only part that is unique to Python is that functions implicitly return `None` when there is no return statement.

Comment: I found the explanation in the answer above useful for understanding but it didn't provide any direction or advice on how to actually resolve the problem. Thanks for keeping it simple!

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to return the value when `x > 9`. Without the return value, the function will "return" `None`.

Comment: so in summary i need to put return on both the condition is it ?

Comment: @AlexKey: In the code above, yes, you will return the value of evaluating `test(x - 10)`